# how to get the lan messenger back

Tags: qsystemtrayicon

i installed LAN messenger in my Ubuntu 12.04 PC.  it is working well.
accidentally i **checked the box don't show system tray icon** in the settings.
so now i cant bring back its interface.
but its working in background.
i want the interface back urgently.
what should i do to get this back?
in tried these steps
1. reinstalled LAN messenger
2. reset the unity
3. checked the system tray white list [its in the white list but not in tray]

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://lanmsngr.sourceforge.net/faq.php), LAN messenger stores its config files in:

```
$HOME/.config/lmc/lmc.ini
```

So you should remove that file.

```
rm -vf $HOME/.config/lmc/lmc.ini
```

Then restart the program.